# (Не) спеша

Tags: орфография

*Таня (не) спеша поднялась, подошла к вешалке, долго одевалась, путаясь в застёжках пальто и нервно покусывая губы.*

(Не) спеша в данном случае пишется слитно или раздельно и какой частью речи является?

Спасибо.

Comment: По моему мнению:

1) русским следует писать наречие "неспеша" слитно,

2) детям и нерусским можно объяснять, что наречие "неспеша" образовалось из частицы "не" и деепричастия "спеша", образованного от инфинитива "спешить",

3) нерусским можно объяснять, что наречия "неспеша" и "медленно" - синонимы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Не спеша" в любом случае является деепричастием, образованным от глагола "спешить", но не выделяется запятыми, так как имеет наречное значение образа действия, может быть заменено наречием "медленно".Естественно, частица "не" с деепричастием пишется раздельно

Comment: +1. К тому же есть уже наречие *неспешно*.

Answer (score 11):

Слово ***не спеша*** пишется раздельно.
Наречие - очень "живая" часть речи, постоянно пополняемая новыми образованиями.
Лет 30-40 назад о слове ***не спеша*** в учебниках было написано: *деепричастие в роли наречия, или - деепричастие с наречным значением.*  (Да и сейчас еще можно встретить)
 А есть в учебниках, в том числе и школьных, слово ***не спеша*** и как наречие (способ образования - переход из одной части речи в другую). Т.е. мы наблюдаем процесс образования наречия из деепричастия. Кстати, в словаре синонимов, в словаре Ефремовой: помета - "наречие".

Я бы так и ответила. Слово ***не спеша*** - наречие, образованное от деепричастия с частицей НЕ. Пишется раздельно.

Comment: Всё было бы правильно, если бы не вывод...  
Ну хорошо, допустим "не спеша" - наречие, образованное от деепричастия.   
Но как же тогда быть со словарной фиксацией наречий со слитным написанием?!

Comment: Именно поэтому и идет переход к слитному написанию. Норма меняется. Ведь пишется же предлог "Несмотря на" слитно с НЕ. хотя деепричастие раздельно. Процесс идет по правильному пути:  слово должно писаться слитно.Повторюсь. мы наблюдаем процесс образования наречий. Было уточнено, что вопрос из учебника - поэтому такой ответ. Все-таки словарь словарю рознь, фиксация только началась. Увидим в орфографическом словаре Института русского языка АН - будем писать слитно.

Comment: Полностью согласна, при подготовке к ЕГЭ мы говорим о наречиях и наречных выражениях - не спеша - наречное выражение(при морф. разборе говорим НАРЕЧИЕ), поэтому не выделяется запятыми, но пишется раздельно, как с деепричастием, значением которого мотивировано, потому что процесс словообразования этого наречия не завершён, так же, как и на скаку - точно наречие, но пишется, как сущ. с предлогом, потому что сочетается в предложении пока как существительное: можно сказать "на всём скаку".С ходу, без удержу,под мышкой - то же самое.

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае наречие: "как?", "каким образом?" (Лёжа читать вредно).

Comment: @Инна, да не всё так просто. Как вы напишете "читай (не) лёжа"?   
Или ещё пример: бросать не глядя. Тоже отвечает на вопросы как?, каким образом? Но вряд ли кто назовёт не глядя наречием.

Comment: @Элен Она бы написала "Не читай лёжа".

Comment: Тут уже называли: "Лет 30-40 назад о слове не спеша в учебниках было написано: деепричастие в роли наречия, или - деепричастие с наречным значением".

Answer (score 1):

Не отвергая всего написанного, предлагаю писать раздельно, как в словаре. 
Из двух вариантов: обычного наречия и деепричастия в роли наречия первый куда естественнее.

ЗЫ. А авторов учебника пытать каленым железом, пока не выдадут тайные знания. А когда выдадут - сослать в Сибирь учить грамоте чукчей, которые слово "спешить" не понимают.

Answer (score 0):

Тут все просто - не спеша принимать решение и принимать решение неспеша: в одном случае - не торопясь, в другом случае - медленно.

Comment: Прочтите все, что уже отвечено.